# Is is a good practice to call a method inside another method? - PHP

Tags: php

I would like to know if it's recommended to do this:

```
class User {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function exists($token) {
        //return true if token exists otherwise return false
    }
    public function createSession($token) {
        if($this->exists($token))
            //create session
        else
            //redirect
    }
}
```

I think it could be not recommended in case of a change in the exists method of the class but I think that'll not happen, What do you recommend me to do?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be recommended? If you don't call the method, you have to duplicate its code. The point of writing functions is to have it in just one place.

Comment: Opinions will vary, but mine is that this is fine. Functions should have a single (simple) purpose, more complex logic means you should have a "wrapper" function that calls other functions in a specific order.

Comment: I don't understand what you meanwhen you write "I think that'll not happen". What won't happen?

Comment: Barmar, I think the method won't change its logic or what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with calling methods from other methods. In many designs, it's critical that you do this. This allows you to create subclasses that redefine the method, and the new definition will be called.

So if you do:

```
class SpecialUser extends User {
    public function exists($token) {
        // determine token existence in some other way
    }
}
```

You can then do:

```
$s = new SpecialUser;
$s->createSession($someToken);
```

and it will make use of the special way that `SpecialUser` checks tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I do that all the time, when i notice my method is too long i segregate it and create another private method or protected method. Another reason is so it could be reuse for another method.

Here's an example:

```
class Download extends PHPExcel{

    public function excel2007()
    {
        $excelFormat = $this->excelFormat();
    }

    public function excel2003()
    {
        $excelFormat = $this->excelFormat();
    }

    private function excelFormat()
    {
        return [

            'font_bold' => [

                'font' => array(
                    'bold' => true
                )

            ],
            'font_size' => [

                'font' => array(
                    'size' => 10
                )   

            ],
            'align_center' => [

                'alignment' => array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER)    

            ]
        ];
    }
}
```